# TcpListener doesn't answer

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I m trying develope a socket program. Here is apart of my code:

```
   TcpListener TcpDinleyici = new TcpListener(7091);
   TcpDinleyici.Start();
   Socket IstemciSoket = TcpDinleyici.AcceptSocket();
```

Program is waiting after the last row and does'nt answer. Do you have any suggestion about this problem?

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is waiting a connection from a client.